# Where to put front facing shed door hinges

Tags: doors, door-frame, hinges

I am almost done my shed except I need to hang my double barn doors. The hinges on most sheds are screwed from the outside so the hinge is completely on the exterior and sitting on the trim. I have a my shed t1-11 siding flush with the framing , however I added a 1inch board around the edges of the opening to create a door jam and then sized my door accordingly. The exterior of the door opening is going to be trimmed with white pvc 3.5inch wide and flush to the door jamb so it is not exposed. My issue though is the door hinge holes that should screw into the framing are not going to hit the 2x4 framing but instead fall right where the 1inch thick door jamb meets the 2x4 door framing.

The hinges I’ve tried are similar to this:

https://www.lowes.com/pd/National-Hardware-9-11-16-in-Black-Gate-Hinge/50414156

So I have three options:

1. Move the hinges farther away from shed door edge such that the pivot point falls more on the trim of the shed.
2. Move the hinges farther into the door so I can hit the 1incb thick door jamb and use that to hold the door. My only concern is the 1inch thick boards are too thin and could split over time. Also just drilling in could split it since these are .25inch thick bolts.
3. Used these door hinges which have a deeper plate to try and hit the 2x4 framing however their weight limit is 22.5lbs each according to Lowe’s but my door is 80lbs and I want to use three hinges a door. https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-Hardware-Essentials-6-in-Black-4x4-Hybrid-T-Hinge-1-Pack/5005431669

Considering the wood door and the door stoppers I’m going to add tk the door jamb can expand and shrink with the weather I would expect the placement of the hinge is important as it’s pivot point will create additional areas of stress on the shed depending on its location. So what should I do I’m this scenario? I could remove the door jamb so the hinges fall on the 2x4s but my doors were cut to size so would be 2inches short in width!

For reference this is similar application of the shed hinges.

[image: shed door hinges]

Comment: A drawing/sketch (or perhaps picture) would help this question immensely. Drawing/sketch could more clearly convey the relationship of parts and the constraints applied (i.e. I think you want non-exposed hinges as on a regular door, but not clear on that. The fact that you say "most sheds" seems to imply that this is somehow different. Tell us how it's different, if it is.)

Comment: I will add a sketch later today when I am by the computer. I have included a pic though for reference now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Question remains unclear, but if external hinges are what you need, just expand your sources to get different styles with more reach that Lowes may not carry. Gate hinges from an agricultural supply will be available in sizes that will carry your load with ease.

[image: adjustable gate hinge from hardwarehut.com]

[image: Strap hinge from jwright.com]

[image: Strap hinge from menards.com]

You might need to add some blocking to provide a place to bolt the longer versions to.